# Prove that $\cos\sqrt x$ is not a periodic function.

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, proof-writing, periodic-functions

Prove that $\cos\sqrt x$ is not a periodic function.

My solution goes like this:

> If $\cos\sqrt x$  is a periodic function , then let $T$ be its period . Now, $\cos\sqrt x=\cos\sqrt {x+T}$  . So, we get, $\sqrt {x+T}\pm\sqrt {x}=2k\pi$. Now, for a particular $k\in\mathbb {Z}$ , this identity is impossible because the left member is a variable continous argument in $x$ , while its right member is a constant. Hence, $\cos\sqrt x$ is not a periodic function.

Is the above solution correct? Is it valid? If not, where is it going wrong?...

Comment: A (small?) mistake with your reasoning is that $k$ depends on $x$, so $2k\pi$ is not constant. The continuity of the square root function is not sufficient to conclude, since $\sin$ is continuous and $\cos(\sin(x))$ is obviously periodic.

Comment: Also, $\cos\sqrt{x+T} =\cos\sqrt(x)$ implies that $\sqrt{x+T}=\sqrt{x}+2k\pi$ or $\sqrt{x+T}=-\sqrt{x}+2k\pi$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: @lonestudent Thanks a lot! I do get it now...But my proof holds valid , right?Thank you...

Comment: @Franklin I will expand my answer.

Comment: @Franklin I expanded my answer, if my still doesn't work,  don't hesitate note to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is equivalent to:

> Find the constant $T≠0$, such that $\cos {\sqrt x}=\cos \sqrt{x+T}$ holds, $\forall x≥0$.

This also implies that, $T>0$.

We claim that, such constant $T≠0$ doesn't exist.

*Proof:* Let $x=0$. Then you have:

$$\begin{align}&\cos \sqrt T=1\\
\implies &\sqrt T=2πn,\; n\in\mathbb Z^{+}\\
\implies &T=4π^2n^2,\;n\in\mathbb Z^{+}.\end{align}$$

Now, let $x=4π^2$. We obtain:

$$
\begin{align}&\cos 2π=\cos \sqrt {4π^2+T}=1\\
\implies &\cos 2π\sqrt {n^2+1}=1\\
\implies &\sqrt {n^2+1}=k,\;k\in\mathbb Z^{+}\\
\implies &n^2+1=k^2\\
\implies &(k-n)(k+n)=1\\
\implies &n=0 \;\text{or}\; T=0\\
&\text {A contradiction .}\end{align}
$$

---

**Explanation:**

Just because you missed a small detail, your proof couldn't work.

You derived the following relationship:

$$\sqrt {x+T}\pm\sqrt {x}=2kπ,\,k\in\mathbb Z$$

Then, that's correct and you are right.

But observe that, this doesn't imply us, you can consider $2πk$ as a constant for a particular $k\in\mathbb Z$.

This implies that,

> For all $x≥0$, does there always exist $k\in\mathbb Z^{+}$ and an independent non-zero constant $T$, such that:
> $$
> \begin{align}\sqrt {x+T}\pm\sqrt {x}&=2k\pi,k\in\mathbb Z\end{align}
> $$
> holds $?$

In other words, you can also understand this statement as follows:

If $\cos \sqrt x=\cos \sqrt{x+T}$, then

$$\sqrt {x+T}\pm\sqrt {x}=2\pi k,\,k\in\mathbb Z$$

holds, *for some* $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Therefore, we cannot say that the right-hand side should be a constant even for a particular $k\in\mathbb Z$.

For instance, you can take

$$\cos 2π=\cos 4π=1$$

This implies,

$$4π-2π=2π×\color {red}{1}$$

or

$$4π+2π=2π×\color {red}{3}$$

Now take,

$$\cos 2π=\cos 6π=1$$

This yields,

$$6π-2π=2π×\color {red}{2}$$

or

$$6π+2π=2π×\color {red}{4}$$

We see that,  since $k$ is not a constant, we cannot consider the right-hand side as a constant for any particular $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @lonestudent Thanks a lot ! I do get it now...Thank you!...

Answer (score 1):

The idea is essentially correct but you should make it more precise (also, it is false that $\cos(a)=\cos(b)$ iff the variables differ by a multiple of $2\pi$).

Suppose that $T>0$ is (one of) the periods of $f(x):=\cos(\sqrt{x})$. Then
$$
\forall x \in \mathbf{R}, \quad f(x)=f(x+T). \quad \quad (\star)
$$
Now, $\cos(a)=\cos(b)$ if and only if there exists $k \in \mathbf{Z}$ such that $a+b=2k\pi$ or $a-b=2k\pi$.

Pick $x_0 \in \mathbf{R}$ such that $0<|\sqrt{x+T}-\sqrt{x}|<2\pi$ for all $x\to x_0$, which is possible since $\sqrt{x+T}-\sqrt{x}\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$.

Pick some $x_\star\ge x_0$ such that $\sqrt{x_\star}+\sqrt{x_\star+T}$ is not a multiple of $2\pi$ (which is possible simply because it attains uncountably many values, while the multiple of $2\pi$ are countably many).

For such choice of $x_\star$, we have by construction that $\sqrt{x_\star+T}+\sqrt{x_\star}$ is not a multiple of $2\pi$ and, in addition, $0<\sqrt{x_\star+T}-\sqrt{x_\star}<2\pi$ (hence also $\sqrt{x_\star+T}-\sqrt{x_\star}$ cannot be a multiple of $2\pi$).

It follows that $f(x_\star) \neq f(x_\star+T)$, which contradicts $(\star)$.

Comment: Thank you! I have edited my answer a bit...is it valid now?...

Comment: @Franklin No: your integer $k$ may depend on $x$. Your proof only shows that there are no integer $k$ which satisfy your identity "uniformly on $x$". However, I believe you already got this point from the comments above